# Higher analogue of the Auslander-Bridger transpose

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra and $M$ a module with $Ext^i(M,A)=0$ for $i=1,...,n-2$.
Then in case $P_{n-1} \rightarrow ... \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ is the beginning of a minimal projective resolution of $M$, we get an exact sequence
$0 \rightarrow M^{*} \rightarrow P_0^{*} \rightarrow ... \rightarrow P_{n-1}^{*}$
Here $(-)^{*}=Hom_A(-,A)$.
In case $n=2$, the cokernel of the map $P_0^{*} \rightarrow P_1^{*}$ is the well known Auslander-Bridger transpose $Tr(M)$ of $M$.

> Question: Is there a name or nice expression for the cokernel $P_{n-2}^{*} \rightarrow P_{n-1}^{*}$ for general $n \geq 3$?

Comment: Isn't your $\mathrm{Tr}(M)$ what people call the Auslander--Reiten transpose? Or am I missing something? (Perhaps just different nomenclature?)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think Tr is called Auslander-Bridger transpose (which exists for any noetherian ring) while $\tau$=DTr is called Auslander-Reiten translate for Artin algebras.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks! :)

Comment: You probably already know that the cokernel of $P_{n-2}^{*} \rightarrow P_{n-1}^{*}$ is $\text{Tr }\Omega^{n-2}M$. I don't know a name, but Auslander and Bridger gave it a symbol, $J_{n-2}M$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks, one can find that in their book. I would hope that somewhere in the literature there has appeared an official name for that and not just a symbol. (maybe in the theory of general noetherian rings, which I do not follow very closely)

Comment: If you apply the duality to $\operatorname{Tr}\Omega^{n-2}(M)$, then you get the $(n-1)$-Auslander-Reiten translation of $M$ (see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870806001721).